# Optimizing or change 5.1 upmix method

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

Is there a way to adjust the stereo to 5.1 upmix method? 
 Under Windows this seems to work perfectly or sounds very harmonious. For example with the onboard card or an Asus STX2. Under Ubuntu (or generally with Linux) the upmix sounds terrible. Hard to describe, but there seems to be no finesse behind it. The sound pushes somehow and sounds wrongly positioned. All other settings for sound optimization like pulse daemon.conf, resamplig method, upmix on off, channelmap, lfe mapping, crossovers, etc. are completely clear to me. In stereo I get a very nice sound, but unfortunately it doesn't work in my room. I can't find anything about this topic.

Questions:
Can the upmix be adjusted in a config? (Not just the channelmap, more the way it works - frequency filters each channel, timings, phaseshifts, etc.)
Are there alternative plugins that can be integrated. Or if so, are there any examples?

BR and thanks!
Mathias

Comment: It would be helpful to know how your sound setup is physically configured.  Are you testing this with true 5.1 speakers?  If so, how are the speakers connected to your computer?  I actually observe the *opposite* problem; that Windows doesn't upmix stereo to surround.  I would suggest that you adjust sound settings in System Settings.  Perhaps you have set the output to 2.0 and you need to adjust it to 5.1.  If you don't actually have 5.1 speakers, you will need to adjust your sound settings accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have troubles with the setup. I have true 5.1 speakers. They are connected in the right way. 5.1 upmix is working correct (speaker test, channel are where they should inkl. lfe and a stereo signal would be upmixed correctly) That´s not the problem. Its just they way pulse/alsa do the upmix is not very good in my opinion. Its not a problem, is more about if it is possible to configure the way alsa/pulse do that upmix. There are several ways to upmix stereo to 5.1. The question is, is it possible to configure or change that in some config file? - Thanks! Mathias